# use of trunc date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

can anyone explain me the working of trunc(date) function in oracle.
my query is as below.

```
select trunc(tran_date) from tablename;
```

i have not passed any format type.
If i compare the date present in table without having trunc(date) it will not give any output.
and if compare date table with trunc(date) it will give me proper ouptut.
please explain how it is working.
and is there any replacement for trunc function as it is taking too much time.

Answer (score 2):

`trunc(tran_date)` returns the date portion of the `date` column with no time component (which is midnight at the start of the day).

Despite its name, the `date` data type in Oracle includes the time.  This is even more confusing because you sometimes do not see the time in the result set (depending on how you access the data).

The dates that you are comparing to have no time component.  So, the comparison works with `trunc()`.  But the time component on `tran_date` prevents the comparison from working without `trunc()`.

Comment: Yes I can not see time in the result set, so what will be different method so that i will get the time in result set or is there any replacement for the trunc function to compare date.

Comment: @GurunathKudalkar . . . In my experience, when I use `timestamp` columns I see the time component.

Comment: I think this is not fully correct. `trunc(tran_date)` truncates the date value to midnight time. The time component is not NULL, i.e. it still exist. It just gets the value `00:00:00`.